# Problem with uploading dht11 data

Tags: python, pi-3

I'm trying to upload some data into thingspeak from DHT11 sensor.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT 
import urllib

while True:
   print("STARTS UPLOADING...")

   baseURL = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=0SKA2NQJ31NBMJA1"

   try:
      humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(11,4)
      hum = str(humidity)
      temp = str(temperature)
      f = urllib.urlopen(baseURL +"&field1="+temp+"&field2="+hum)
      print(f.read())
      print(temp+ " " + hum+ " " )
      f.close()
   except:
      print('exiting.')
      break
```

Whenever I execute this program, it does not enter the data into thingspeak. It just exits.

Need some immediate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the official documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/update-channel-feed.html) and the example [here](https://github.com/DexterInd/BrickPi_Python/blob/7e4f1a8597b5e44e2e2fd07531f782af363c7fe1/Project_Examples/Thingspeak%20Temperature%20Logging/Thermometer_Thingspeak.py) I believe you need to perform a HTTP POST to upload the data rather than the default GET you have used.

There is a related question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889872/how-to-post-api-in-thingspeak-comusing-urllib-in-python)

There appears to be a dedicated python library for thingspeak [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/thingspeak/) which might be worth while checking out. The docs for that are [here](http://thingspeak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)